# iOS MVVM RxSwift + Realm

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, realm

Вопрос следующий. вот есть у меня во viewModel:

```
var people = Variable<[Person]>([])
```

Во вью контроллере я подписываюсь вот так:

```
peopleViewModel.people.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: { (people) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.peopleTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }, onError: { (error) in

        }, onCompleted: {

        }) {

        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

И все хорошо работает. Данные загружаются, табличка перезагружается.

Если что Person это объект реалма:

```
class Person: Object {
@objc dynamic var title:  String = ""
@objc dynamic var first:  String = ""
@objc dynamic var last:   String = ""
@objc dynamic var email:  String = ""
@objc dynamic var avatar: String = ""
@objc dynamic var avatarData: Data = Data()
```

}

Вроде пока все ясно.

У меня есть еще один экран. Который отображает данные конкретного Person. На нем же я могу их редактировать. Например, изменить имя. Я, конечно же, ожидал, что когда я изменю какому то Person имя, то сработает next во viewController и табличка перерисуется. Но этого не происходит.

Внимание вопрос! Что собственно нужно сделать чтобы изменения какого-либо свойства объекта в наблюдаемом массиве вызывали next?

Сразу скажу что уже не первый день гуглю и иду пути решения, но так ничего и не нашел. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Спасибо!